# What is @ in "@+id/idname" format mean in android?

Tags: android

[official link here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#LinearLayout)

They say:

> The at sign (@) is required when you're referring to any resource object from XML. It is followed by the resource type (id in this case), a slash, then the resource name (edit_message).

I'm not quite understand what `@` mean, who can give a more specific explanation?

Comment: I think op wants to ask **what is the @ mean?**

Comment: Now I edit my question a little bit.

Comment: @PareshMayani I dont think this is a duplicate both questions have different context

Comment: Thank you. at original it is a little duplicate on description but I reedit later. @SMR

Comment: It was a duplicate question earlier but now updated details has made it more clear and unique!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ID is not already *created*, then `+` will *create* it. You will need it only the first time you refer to that id.

From docs :

> The plus sign (+) before the resource type is needed only when you're
>   defining a resource ID for the first time. When you compile the app,
>   the SDK tools use the ID name to create a new resource ID in your
>   project's gen/R.java file that refers to the EditText element. With
>   the resource ID declared once this way, other references to the ID do
>   not need the plus sign.

Like the docs say, the `@` symbol means you are *referring* to an xml resource. 
For example : `@string/edit_message` means you are trying to refer to a string with the id edit_message defined in an xml file.

Comment: um, then, what is the `@` mean?

Comment: so the `@+id/idname` mean I create a resource which id is "idname" and `@` means I refer to the resource id name after I just create it?

Comment: Actually, - *you try to refer to the resource using "@" and create it (thats why you have the "+") if it is not already present*

Comment: I get it, I have accept your answer and you can add your last comment into your answer, to make it clear.

Answer (score 2):

`@ sign` means you are referring to a `resource` under res folder.

@drawable

refer to a .png or button state images.

**@anim**

refer to animation

**@id/anyID**

refer to any pre Created id

**@+id/createNewID**

**+ create** a new id and name it createNewID and

**+sign only works with id. you cannot use it with anim,drawable.**

**Note**

You can not create any Resource programatically other than id.

Answer (score 1):

In each android project there is a `gen` folder inside `src` where `R.java` is created automatically and all the **IDs of resources** used/created in XMLs belong here.

As the docs say:

> The at sign (@) is required when you're referring to any resource object from XML.

This means that you are going to refer an ID from `R.java` if you add `+` then the corresponding id will be created if it does not exists in `R.java` already. As the docs say:

> The plus sign (+) before the resource type is needed only when you're defining a resource ID for the first time. When you compile the app, the SDK tools use the ID name to create a new resource ID in your project's `gen/R.java` file that refers to the `EditText` element. With the resource ID declared once this way, other references to the ID do not need the plus sign.

So `+` sign is required only when you want to create a new id for the view. If it is already created in the same file then it will simply reuse that id instead of creating a new id with the same name.

**NOTE:** you can use `+` with IDs only.

`@` has so many uses. The one which are used mostly are:

- `@id/` to reference from `R.id`
- `@string/` references `R.string` similarly...
- `@drawable/` -> `R.drawable`
- `@array/` -> `R.array`
- `@color/` -> `R.color`

Finally you can use `@android` to refer resources defined in the android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

**@ is used to give identity or to refer to the existing resource in XML File.**

**'@'** specifies what kind of resource you are about to access.
if you use @id, it will refer to any resources in layout of project.
if you use @string, it will locate to a string that you may usually specify in Strings.XML

there are so many other resources like :
@drawable, @color, @style, @array, @dimen, @layout & @xml..

you can use according to your requirement.