# Why doesn't the "@string/" attribute not have a + sign?

Tags: android, android-xml-attribute

I know that the `+` sign in the `id` attribute of a View indicates that it's a new user defined custom value that must be added to the `R.Java` file. But, in the example XML Button View attributes below, why does the `@string` not have the `+` symbol before the word `string` like the `@+id` attribute?

```
<Button android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

Comment: In this case you are linking an existing resource (string).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28600203/5192105

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti But isn't that a custom string value that will be added to R.Java? So, that should require a `+` sign, right?

Comment: @Swifty No. The string already exists in the resource files (and then in R.string.xxx)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Do you mean that this is because the string resource is a predefined static value where as the id value in R.Java is volatile, requiring a rebuild every time the app is built and run in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plus symbol, [**`+`**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource), indicates that this is a new resource ID and the **`Android Asset Packaging Tool`** will create a new resource integer in the **`R.java`** class, if it doesn't already exist.

[**@string**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) - Defined in resource files. The **`<string>`** element's name is used as the resource ID.